# Can Kivy be runned on windows?

Tags: kivy, python-3.7

This question has been asked a lot of times and I guess it's my turn to ask it now. I'm on windows using WSL2. I ran a simple kivy code to simulate a chess board.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color 

class ChessBoard(Widget):             
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        "Making the chess board"
        super(ChessBoard, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            self.board = Rectangle(source = 'blank-chess-board.gif', pos = (125, 90), size = (520, 520))


class ChessApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ChessBoard()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ChessApp().run()
```

It said: [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
Yesterday, I fixed the bug by installing miniconda and running my program on the command prompt.
But today, when I run it on the command prompt, it doesn't work. I haven't change the code since yesterday. What am I doing wrong? Thanks, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use WSL, just use windows. Also, when asking questions about errors always post the full traceback.

Comment: Ok. But I know the WSL thing will make an error, that's why I ran it in the command prompt. But their is still an error

Comment: And are you the same guy in discord?